# To show "no such result found" in while loop?

Tags: php, while-loop

```
<?php
$s=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bus_detail WHERE source_point='$source_point' AND destination_point='$destination' AND `".$day."` = 'yes'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($s)) {
    $count+=1;
    ?>
    <tr class="td_text">
    <td><?php echo $count; ?></td>
    <td><input name="bus_name" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['bus_name'];?>" class="input_box" /></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['bus_no'];?></td>
    <td><input name="bus_id" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['bus_id'];?>" style="border:0px; width:15px; text-align:left;" /></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['departure_time'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['arrival_time'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['duration'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['seat_availablity'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['price'];?></td>
    <td><a href="book.php?bus_id=<?php echo $row['bus_id'];?>"><input type="submit" value="Book Now" style="border:0px;" class="book" title="Search here" /></a></td></tr>
    <?php
}
?>
```

This code is totaly alright. But if there is no result according to the query I want to show "No such result found". I tried `while(!$s)`, but no result. Any help?

I want to show the result in the blank field
[image]

Comment: Should i use it inside the tr or out side ??

Comment: Outside and After the while block, which means the while never loop

Comment: `$count+=1;` ... nice one ...

Comment: You are [blockquoting every single one of your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3024181/sarmistha?tab=questions). You should stop abusing formatting, right now.

Comment: Stop using `>` in front of your sentences. They are not quotes. It just messes up your posts.

Comment: uhh /..then how can i represent my sentences ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use mysql_num_rows($s), this will return the number of rows the query fetched, if there is no result, number of rows returned will be 0.

Add below line before executing the while loop,

```
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($s);
if($num_rows == 0) {
  echo "No such result found";
  return;
}
```

Comment: You need to place before while loop.

Comment: <?php
$s=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bus_detail WHERE source_point='$source_point' AND destination_point='$destination' AND `".$day."` = 'yes'");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($s);
if($num_rows == 0) {
  echo "No such result found";
  return;
}
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($s)) {
    $count+=1;
    ?>
    <tr class="td_text">
     .......
}

Comment: it's good but it's blocking my all jquery effects as well as another codes n queries also

Comment: in that case use below code,

<?php $s=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bus_detail WHERE source_point='$source_point' AND destination_point='$destination' AND ".$day." = 'yes'"); $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($s); if($num_rows == 0) { echo "No such result found"; } else {while($row=mysql_fetch_array($s)) { $count+=1; ?> <tr class="td_text"> ....... } }

Comment: hey fixed :).. i just removed the return part n now it running fine.. thank you soo much.. :)

Comment: see my result , how it's showing ?? but i want to show it after the heading bar ?? @rumi

Comment: Try this,
<?php $s=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bus_detail WHERE source_point='$source_point' AND destination_point='$destination' AND ".$day." = 'yes'"); $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($s);if($num_rows == 0) {?> <tr class="td_text">
    <td colspan=10 style='text-align:center'><?php echo "No such result found"; ?></td> } <?php else {while($row=mysql_fetch_array($s)) {......}

Answer (score 3):

[image]

> showing like this .. cant i put the result after the heading bar ???

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql_num_rows to check how many rows have been returned:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($s) > 0)
{
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($s)) {
        $count+=1;
    ?>
        <tr class="td_text">
        <td><?php echo $count; ?></td>
        <td><input name="bus_name" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['bus_name'];?>" class="input_box" /></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['bus_no'];?></td>
        <td><input name="bus_id" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['bus_id'];?>" style="border:0px; width:15px; text-align:left;" /></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['departure_time'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['arrival_time'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['duration'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['seat_availablity'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['price'];?></td>
        <td><a href="book.php?bus_id=<?php echo $row['bus_id'];?>"><input type="submit" value="Book Now" style="border:0px;" class="book" title="Search here" /></a></td></tr>
    <?php
    }
}
else
   echo "No such result found";
```

Comment: i knw that , i just want to show "no such result found" if there is no result according to the query

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. This way you'd either show that there are no results or output them as you already do. Isn't that what you're trying to do?

Comment: yeah like this.. but i ve used while loop for it... so where should i place it ??

Comment: hey it's showin error , as my php tag ends after count+ and if m starting another tag for the else part, it's showing me unexpected elese syntax error

Comment: You should see if you close and open PHP tags correctly. All open flow control brackets have to be closed one way or another. It's hard to tell where's your mistake without seeing any code. I'll try to update my piece with what you provided.

Comment: no listen it's been fixed by rumi's answer :) .. thank you for your answer also

Answer (score 0):

Detect the rows count as suggested above, then keep the no result string in a variable.

```
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($s);
if($num_rows == 0) {
  $string_no_result = "No such result found";
  return;
}
```

After the TR and TD for the heading bar, print the no result string.

```
 echo $string_no_result;
```